# Defining empty array issue

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define a empty array so i can define values to it further down in code but i keep getting 'subscript out of range', Run time error '9' on this line:

```
ReDim VectorToSum(0 To q-1)
```

Am an unsure why.
This is the full code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DefferedRev()
    Dim NoMonths As Range
    Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")


    If ws.Range("B40").Value = ws.Range("C82").Value Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(48, 5), ws.Cells(48, 7)).Value = 0
    Else
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To 7
            Dim q As Long
            q = (i Mod NoMonths) - 5

            Dim VectorToSum() As String
            ReDim VectorToSum(0 To q-1)

            Dim w As Long
            For w = 0 To q-1
                VectorToSum(w) = (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w

            ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

i have tried this:

```
            q = (i Mod NoMonths) - 5

            Dim VectorToSum() As Long


            Dim w As Long
            For w = 0 To q
            ReDim VectorToSum(w)
                VectorToSum(w) = (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w

            ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum)
        Next i
```

but I just get a run time error 5 on following line:

```
ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum)
```

Comment: What is the value of `q` when the error is thrown? My guess is that it is negative, which suggests that you need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also -- what is the point of loading numbers into an array in a loop just to sum them? Just form the sum as you go along.

Comment: @JohnColeman. sorry im new to vba and didn't know you could do that. How would i do that?

Comment: Just initialize a variable, say `sum`, to zero and then in the body of a loop have the line `sum = sum + value_to_be_added`. Also -- you should read up on the difference between `ReDim` and `ReDim Preserve`. You were erasing older values in each pass through the loop, so even if you debugged it, it wouldn't have done what you expected.

Comment: @Tom `q` is declared as `Long`, although OP isn't declaring the variables at the top of the sub but is instead using more of a Java-style idiom.

Comment: @JohnColeman You're right - missed that in OP's code

Answer (score -1):

@JohnColeman

done your suggestions, now i'm getting run time error 6 on this line:

```
                Sum = Sum + (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
```

What do you think may be the issue now?
full code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DefferedRev()
    Dim NoMonths As Range
    Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Licence Central").Range("C13")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("73 Licence C")


    If ws.Range("B40").Value = ws.Range("C82").Value Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(48, 5), ws.Cells(48, 7)).Value = 0
    Else
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To 7
            Dim q As Integer
            q = (i - 5 Mod NoMonths)

           ' Dim VectorToSum() As String
            'ReDim VectorToSum(0)

            Dim w As Long
            Dim Sum As Long
            Sum = 0
            For w = 0 To q
                Sum = Sum + (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w

            ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Sum
        Next i

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Asking a question in the guise of an answer isn't appropriate on Stack Overflow. Perhaps ask another question. What is `NoMonth`? You declared it as a range but are treating it as a value. Why not just declare it as e.g. a `Long` and assign the cell value to it? Without having a [mcve], it is hard to know what the issue is. Dividing by a number which is almost zero can lead to an overflow.

Answer (score -2):

Your array is  a single dimension so you can remove your issues relating to Redim by switching to a scripting.dictionary (or ArrayList)

For a Scripting.Dictionary you will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scritpting Runtime

For an array list you will need to add a reference to mscorlib to which you will need to browse to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll (or Frameword64 if you are using 64 bit Office)

```
Public Sub DefferedRev()
    Dim NoMonths As Range
    Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")


    If ws.Range("B40").Value = ws.Range("C82").Value Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(48, 5), ws.Cells(48, 7)).Value = 0
    Else
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To 7
            Dim q As Long
            q = (i Mod NoMonths) - 5

            Dim VectorToSum As Scripting.Dictionary
            Dim w As Long
            Set VectorToSum = New Scripting.Dictionary

            For w = 0 To q - 1
                VectorToSum.Add w, (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w

            ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum.Items)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```